# How strtok handles newlines?

Tags: c++, string, string-parsing

I am trying to read data as tokens from a string, containing several lines.
I use the code

```
    char * pch;
    pch = strtok ((char*)MyStr.c_str()," ,|,\n"); int i = 0;
    while (pch != NULL && i++ < 10)
    {
      cerr << i << ':' << pch << ' ';
      pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
    }
```

The input is

```
std::string SP1271 = "1271,1\n"
"0,44248,8,45040,20,1,0,100\n"
"545,590,603,564,566,598,569,585,586,578\n";
```

and the output is

```
1:1271 2:1
0 3:44248 4:8 5:45040 6:20 7:1 8:0 9:100
545 10:590
```

Is it legal to use '\n' as separator?

Comment: Why not compile and check?

Comment: not a good idea to use `strtok` on a constant `c_str()` return (with forced non-const cast, dirty hack!!). You should look at a real way to split a text according to separators in _real_ c++.

Comment: Yes, it is legal to use `\n` as a separator. It's a character like any other. Note though that you only pass `\n` as a separator in the first `strtok` call, but not in any follow-up calls. That's why `"1\n0"` ends up as a single token - not because `\n` is somehow special, but because you don't treat it as a separator for any token but the very first.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The current approach can be salvaged by replacing `(char*)MyStr.c_str()` with `&MyStr[0]`

Comment: Perfer to use `std::string` methods for parsing text.  The `strtok` function **modifies** the C-Style character array that is passed to it.

Comment: _"(char*)MyStr.c_str()"_ What are you doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very bad idea to use `strtok()` because this function might alter the original string, which is not supposed to be changed, because it's `const`.

Also, even if this could work, you didn't foresee '\n' as token separator in the loop of subsequent `strtok()`. So better align all your token separator strings.

Why not use C++ functionality:

```
size_t pe;
for (size_t pb=0; pe=MyStr.find_first_of(" ,-\n", pb); pb=pe+1)
{
    cout  << MyStr.substr(pb, (pe==string::npos ? pe:pe-pb))<< " ";
    if (pe==string::npos)
        break; 
}
```